# How to create link in for loop via Datetime

Tags: c#

I just want to create a text(link) something like this for every month of a year

```
May, 2013 
April, 2013 
March, 2013 
February, 2013
January, 2013 
December, 2012
```

to do this I have created this for loop

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var end = DateTime.Now.AddYears(20);

for (DateTime time = start; time <= end; time = time.AddMonths(1))
{
    //month and year
}
```

but I'm not sure because it does not work :(

Comment: Should work. What error do you get and on what line exactly?

Comment: Should *not* work. His `end` that is supposed to terminate the loop ends in 20 *years*

Comment: I'm not sure about the code because I want to compare the now date and create a new line of the now date is in new month

Comment: @EricNielsen Also, "it does not work" is the *worst* way you can describe a problem. You get a compile error? Runtime exception? Unexpected output? **Be more specific**

Comment: You shouldn't set a DateTime object equal to another DatTime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 31);
List<string> list = new List<string>();
for (DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1); startDate.Month <= endDate.Month; startDate = startDate.AddMonths(1))
{
    list.Add(startDate.ToString("MMMM, yyyy"));
    if (startDate.Month == endDate.Month)
        break;
}
```

For output:

```
foreach(string str in list)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Output would be:

```
January, 2013
February, 2013
March, 2013
April, 2013
May, 2013
June, 2013
July, 2013
August, 2013
September, 2013
October, 2013
November, 2013
December, 2013
```

Comment: Wouldn't that break out at the first instance of the months being equal and ignore the amount of years required?

Comment: thanks , seems to be correct but before test I have to say that I wanna to create it for every ! (for later years) Not only for 2013 , how can I edit above code to do that ??

Comment: @EricNielsen, specify the year accordingly.

Comment: it will create the year also ?? if the year will turn to 1014 ??

Comment: Not really sure about your question, but you can set the start  date and end date to your requirement, like `DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)` and `DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2050, 12, 31);` would give you month for year 2000 to 2050.

Comment: your solution is correct but I want to list the name of current and past month of 2013 anytime and add month when it begins , please help me about this

Comment: No no I just want to begin from this month(5/2/2013) and create current month and current year by having the past month and year in the list Not month and year of future

Comment: @EricNielsen - then have `DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 5, 2)` (fixed) and `DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;` (relative). So if you recalculate the list in 20 years, you will get all the months from `2013-05-02` until `2033-05-02`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MMMM` to get the months.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetMonthsOfYear(DateTime startDate, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    var end = startDate.Add(timeSpan);

    for (DateTime time = startDate; time <= end; time = time.AddMonths(1))
    {
        yield return time.ToString("MMMM, yyyy");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var monthsOfYear = GetMonthsOfYear(start, start.AddYears(20) - start);
```